# Managed metadata error: This operation cannot be completed. the term store may be unavailable

Tags: managed-metadata

I am using sp 2010. I have a managed metadata global structure implemented. It was working always fine, but today it is empty and gives me this error:

> this operation cannot be completed. the term store may be unavailable

When I go to the library which has a managed metadata column. And add a new document the managed metadata tree is empty:

[image]
But when I fill in some text in the field it finds some results. I can also save the document.

[image]

When I go to the site settings -> Termstore Management Tool I got the error:

> this operation cannot be completed. the term store may be unavailable

[image]

What is going wrong? Another site collection is working fine.

Comment: Is there something related in the ULS logs and / or windows event log (Application)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange! one day later it worked. I did nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

Out of the many reasons that may have caused this...one of them is that the application pool of central admin may have restarted during the first time you tried.

Did you try again immediately after some time ?

Since it started again for you , this is the only reason that makes sense.